# Error in setting up Less in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, less

I'm trying to setup Less in Reactjs, and im following this tutorial, [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc). my problem is, after following those steps, I got this error message

> 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

This error show when I add new commands on package.json

```
"scripts": {
     "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/",
     "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
-    "start": "react-scripts start",
-    "build": "react-scripts build",
+    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
+    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
+    "build-js": "react-scripts build",
+    "build": "npm-run-all build-css build-js",
     "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
     "eject": "react-scripts eject"
   }
```

I don't know what to do on this.
Hope you understand me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added `react-scripts` into your `package.json`? If not, do so, `npm install` and go ahead!

Comment: It works sir, thanks, I thought it will overwrite all the changes I made.

Comment: sorry sir, im still wating 1 min